# Using unknown number of datasets in Chart.js

Tags: javascript, php, chart.js

I'm still fairly new to javascript and this has got me banging my head against the wall. I'm sure it's really simple but for some reason I cannot seem to get this working correctly. I have seen similar questions on stackoverflow but I can't make them work for me.

I am trying to plot an unknown number of datasets onto a Chartjs graph. I am able to get the data (using PHP it is output as data attributes on child elements of the canvas) and store them to a variable $rows.

```
var $rows = $('#graphCanvas').find('> div')
```

I then iterate through the rows and calculate the dataset.

```
var colors = [ '#2685CB', '#4AD95A', '#FEC81B', '#FD8D14', '#CE00E6', '#4B4AD3', '#FC3026', '#B8CCE3', '#6ADC88', '#FEE45F'  ];

for (var i=0; i<$rows.length; i++) {
    datasetdata[i] = {
        label:"Test " + i,
        data: getdata($rows[i]),
        backgroundColor: colors[i],
        hoverBackgroundColor: colors[i],
        borderStyle: 'solid',
        borderWidth: 2,
    }
}

function getdata($rows) {
    //returns raw data
}
```

This all works well however the problem starts when I try to use **datasetdata**

```
var graphContext = document.getElementById("graphCanvas").getContext("2d");
var graphData = {
    labels: labels,
    datasets: [datasetdata]
};
```

If I use it with an index it works fine: **datasetdata[0]**

If I knew for sure how many datasets there would be I could just add their indexes and it would be fine.

Any insight into what I'm doing wrong would be great

Comment: Does Chartjs allow for multiple data sets? Did you see this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26397009/how-to-create-datasets-dynamically-for-chart-js-line-chart

Comment: Yes it does, you can plot several datasets on the same graph.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Problem:

You have an extra set of brackets surrounding the `datasetdata` variable.

#### Solution:

Remove the brackets and set the `datasets` to just `datasetdata`:

```
var graphData = {
    labels: labels,
    datasets: datasetdata
};
```

#### Explanation:

The `datasets` option accepts a parameter that is an array of dataset objects. The wanted structure looks as following:

```
datasets: [
    { dataset1 },
    { dataset2 }
]
```

In your code, you surrounded the `datasetdata` by a set of brackets:

```
var graphData = {
    labels: labels,
    datasets: [datasetdata]
};
```

By adding another set of brackets, you are basically setting `datasets` to an array which contains the `datasetdata` array. The code renders a result that looks as following:

```
datasets: [
    [ { dataset1 }, { dataset2 } ]
]
```

If you add select the value of the array at a specific index, you are extracting a single dataset from the `datasetdata` array.

```
var graphData = {
    labels: labels,
    datasets: [datasetdata[0]]
};
```

Your structure is then an array with a single dataset inside it:

```
datasets: [
   { dataset1 }
]
```

This code won't throw and error, since the structure is valid, however, it will only display the first result.

Comment: I knew it would end up being something silly like that. Thanks for your help and taking the time to explain.