# Displaying JSON data in Chartjs

Tags: javascript, json, chart.js

I am trying to use [Chart JS](http://www.chartjs.org/) to create a table with dynamically generated data points coming from my JSON file. The logic of my code looks like so:

```
var datapart;
for (i = 0; i < jsonfile.jsonarray.length; i++){
     datapart += {
          label: jsonfile.jsonarray[i].name,
          data: [jsonfile.jsonarray[i].age] 
     };
}

var config = {
   type: 'line',
   data: {
      labels: ["Graph Line"],
      datasets: [datapart]
   }
}
```

My JSON file meanwhile looks something like so:

```
{
"jsonarray": [
    {
      "name": "Joe",
      "age": 12
    },
    {
      "name": "Tom",
      "age": 14
    }
]
}
```

The `config` variable houses the configuration settings for ChartJS, including setting datapoints. When loaded into ChartJS, `config` provides information needed to display my chart.

Anyhow, my thinking was to use the variable `datapart` as a means of appending the datasets using my for loop. Unfortunately the code produces no results. I understand that my method for appending variables is faulty, but am unsure how to proceed.

How might I go about adding these JSON values to Chart.js?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Your approach on constructing the chart is completely inappropriate. Here is the proper way, that you should follow :

```js
var jsonfile = {
   "jsonarray": [{
      "name": "Joe",
      "age": 12
   }, {
      "name": "Tom",
      "age": 14
   }]
};

var labels = jsonfile.jsonarray.map(function(e) {
   return e.name;
});
var data = jsonfile.jsonarray.map(function(e) {
   return e.age;
});

var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
var config = {
   type: 'line',
   data: {
      labels: labels,
      datasets: [{
         label: 'Graph Line',
         data: data,
         backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 119, 204, 0.3)'
      }]
   }
};

var chart = new Chart(ctx, config);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.6.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thanks! A much better way of including my data. The only issue I am having now is that this prints as one dataset, when I would like both people in my list to be separated into their own dataset.

Comment: Are you sure? Cause that would look something like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/yLaj65sj/). This^^ is the general way.

Comment: Yes, that's the format I'm more going for. Only I am trying to figure out how to make each dataset dynamically, depending on the people on my list.

Comment: Got it figured out! Basically took cues from this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26397009/how-to-create-datasets-dynamically-for-chart-js-line-chart

Comment: One thing about this approach is that you end up looping over the data twice. More efficient to do it in one for loop

Comment: @ɢʀᴜɴᴛ what will jsonfile look like if the json data is coming from an endpoint or baseUrl?

Answer (score 0):

I found the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26397009/2822307) proposed by Bear GRiZZLY XI quite helpful.  Makes use of the for.. loop.

Let's suppose you have a json response from your api as follows:

```
var markschart = document.getElementbyId("markschart");

{
    "labels": "Maths,Geography,Physics,Chemistry,English,Biology,Music",
    "datasets": [
        {
            "label": "Student 3",
            "data": "120, 90, 45, 90, 14, 100, 88",
            "spanGaps": false
        },
        {
            "label": "Student 2",
            "data": "150, 80, 99, 100, 90, 110, 97",
            "spanGaps": false
        },
        {
            "label": "Student 1",
            "data": "140, 100, 89, 134, 120, 78, 56",
            "spanGaps": false
        }
    ]
}
```

in javascript you may handle the response as follows (response contains the above json packet):

```
var mydatasets = [];
var colorslist = ["blue","orange","magenta","green","syrup","navy","bumblebee","turkish","army","ferrari"];

for(var j = 0; j < response.datasets.length; j++) {
  mydatasets.push({label: response.datasets[j].label, boderColor: colorslist[j], data: response.datasets[j].data.splits(','), spanGraphs: true});
}
var subjectsData = {
  labels: response.labels.split(','),
  datasets: mydatasets
}

var options = {
  scales: { 
   yAxes: [{
      ticks: {
             beginAtZero: true
           },
      scaleLabel: {
             display: true,
             labelString: 'Subject Perfomance',
             fontSize: 14
           }
  }]
 }
};

var studentsMarksPerformance = new Chart(markschart, {
      type: "line",
      data: subjectsData ,
      options: options
});
```

The above is not a complete solution but may help with implementing for..each loop in creating a line chart using Chart.js