# I'm using Chartjs with the plugin chartjs datasource and can't specify what parts of data I want to use

Tags: javascript, html, chart.js

I have two datasets I can use for global warming temperature average. CSV https://pkgstore.datahub.io/core/global-temp/annual_csv/data/a26b154688b061cdd04f1df36e4408be/annual_csv.csv and JSON https://pkgstore.datahub.io/core/global-temp/annual_json/data/529e69dbd597709e36ce11a5d0bb7243/annual_json.json. I'm trying to only use GISTEMP as my source. I tried using JSON but couldnt get it to work the way I wanted.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Global Warming</title>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@2.8.0"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-plugin-datasource@0.1.0"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="script.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

    </head>
<body>
    <div class="chartStyle">
        <canvas id="GlobalTempGraph"></canvas>
</div>
</body>
```

```
//global temp graph
var GlobalTempConfig = {

    type: 'line',

    plugins: [ChartDataSource],

    options: {
    legend: {
            display: false
          },  
      scales: {
          xAxes: [{  
            scaleLabel: {
                  display: true,
                  labelString: 'Year',
              }

          }],
          yAxes: [{
              id: 'Temperature',
              gridLines: {
                  drawOnChartArea: false
              },
              scaleLabel: {
                  display: true,
                  labelString: 'Temperature',
              }
          }],

      },

      plugins: {
      datasource: {

          type: 'csv',
          url: 'https://pkgstore.datahub.io/core/global-temp/annual_csv/data/a26b154688b061cdd04f1df36e4408be/annual_csv.csv', //url of csv
          delimiter: ',',
          rowMapping: 'datapoint',
          datasetLabels: true,
          indexLabels: true,
          datapointLabels: false,
          datapointLabelMapping: {
            _dataset: '_dataset',
            _index: 'x',
            x: '',
            y: ''}
    }
  }
    }

};

function effectsGraph(){
    var ctx = document.getElementById('GlobalTempGraph').getContext('2d');
    window.myChart = new Chart(ctx, GlobalTempConfig);
}

window.addEventListener("load", effectsGraph, false);
```

```
.chartStyle{
    height: 50%;
    width: 800px;
}
```

Comment: refer this : - https://stackoverflow.com/a/44990697/9641914

Comment: @satsvelke I can graph data using the json file they had but i've to use data from a server. I tried using getJSON to get the data which worked but I cant graph it.